# How do i format or acces the JSON correctly here?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I feel stupid not finding the answer by myself.

I want to add a customer to a database by sending data to a php file via jquery, AJAX and JSON.

It works but, when I try to access the variables in the object I get an empty response. I don't get why.

Here's my PHP code:

`$connection` passes me the DB connection later on, but I don't access it yet due to debugging

```
function addCustomer($connection){
    $data =  json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $surname = $data['surname'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $street = $data['street'];
    $streetNumber = $data['streetNumber'];
    echo $_POST['data'];
    echo $data;
    echo $name;
}
```

The first two echo give back what i expect, but the third one only outputs `{`

---

And here is the JS code:

```
function addCustomer(){
    var $surname = $('#addCuSurname').val();
    var $name = $('#addCuName').val();
    var $street = $('#addCuStreet').val();
    var $streetNumber = $('#addCuStreetNumber').val();

    if($surname != '' && $name != '' && $street != '' && $streetNumber != ''){

        var customer = '{"surname": "'+ $surname +'", "name": "'+ $name+'", "street": "'+ 
                        $street+'", "streetNumber": '+ $streetNumber +'}';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/backend/customers.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'action': 'addCu', 'data': JSON.stringify(customer)},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response, status) {

            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }, 
        });
    }
}
```

It's probably an error in my JSON syntax I assume, but I didn't find anything that would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to pass it as JSON? You can have nested objects in the `data` parameter, and access them as nested arrays in PHP, e.g. `$_POST['data']['surname']`.

Comment: @Barmar I don't need to, just want to try, it is a starter project for myself, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to stringify something that's already a string.  Try defining customer like so:

```
var customer = {
  surname: $surname,
  name: $name,
  street: $street,
  streetNumber: $streetNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are applying `JSON.stringify()` to the string assigned to customer (yes, it is a *string representing a JSON*):

```
var customer = '{"surname": "'+ $surname +'", "name": "'+ $name+'", "street": "'+ 
                $street+'", "streetNumber": '+ $streetNumber +'}';
```

When you `stringify` it, what you get is a string representing a string representing a JSON. For example, I ran these lines in Firebug:

```
> JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2});
"{"a":1,"b":2}"
> JSON.stringify("{a: 1, b: 2}");
""{a: 1, b: 2}""  // A string representing a string representing a JSON.
```

As you can see, in the first example, I got string representing a JSON. The second example (stringifying a string which represents JSON) returns a sting representing a JSON string. I hope not being too confusing with these ideas. Lets go to the solution.

You have two options. First, you could build a JSON instead of a JSON string:

```
var customer = {
    surname: $surname,
    name: $name,
    street: $street,
    streetNumber: $streetNumber
};
```

Then stringify it.

The other option is to leave the JSON string just like you are building it but not applying `JSON.stringify()` to it.

```
...
data: {'action': 'addCu', 'data': customer},
...
```

I would go with the first solution, since that way you ensure to get a correctly formatted JSON string and it is cleaner than building it by hand.

Comment: Thank you aswell, as i mentioned above, got rid of the problem by this exact solution :D